# calculated field from two fields in separate tables based on a date

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Using PostgreSQL v9.6

Trying average an actual intrusion time based by dividing the total intrusion time for the day by the available uptime for that day grouped by computer.

[Click here for SQLFiddle of this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1b7d9/5)

Query should look something like:

```
SELECT availability.adate, sum(intrusionEvents.duration)/availability.uptime,  intrusionEvents.host
FROM availability LEFT JOIN intrusionEvents ON (availability.adate = intrusionEvents.itime::date)
WHERE availability.adate >= '20171001' AND availability.adate < '20171101'
GROUP BY availability.adate, intrusionEvents.host
ORDER BY availability.adate, intrusionEvents.host
```

(where uptime and intrusionDuration are in seconds...)

In variations of this I'm running into a a couple of issues:

1. In this example, availability.uptime needs to be in the aggregate.
2. I've gotten around this but then I end up with hundreds of rows.

Any suggestions (and examples) on how how to sum up individual durations from a field and then divide it by value from a different table with a matching date would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I added **availability.uptime** in the group by:

```
select availability.adate, sum(intrusionEvents.duration)/availability.uptime,  intrusionEvents.host
FROM availability left join intrusionEvents on (availability.adate = intrusionEvents.itime::date)
WHERE availability.adate >= '20171001' and availability.adate < '20171101'
GROUP by availability.adate, intrusionEvents.host,
availability.uptime
```

Got the below results set:

[image]

Is this what you wanted?